# Question about Julia version 1.8 and XLSX

Tags: julia, spreadsheet, xlsx

I used Julia 1.7
The command
`dfc = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("data.xlsx","sheet1")...)` worked good

After migrating to Julia 1.8 the same command stopped working and generated the following error message:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching iterate(::XLSX.DataTable)
Closest candidates are:
  iterate(!Matched::Union{LinRange, StepRangeLen}) at range.jl:872
  iterate(!Matched::Union{LinRange, StepRangeLen}, !Matched::Integer) at range.jl:872
  iterate(!Matched::T) where T<:Union{Base.KeySet{<:Any, <:Dict}, Base.ValueIterator{<:Dict}} at dict.jl:712
```

what has changed with that command with the new release?

Looking forward to some information

Comment: Are you using the same version of XLSX?

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with the Julia version you are using, and everything with the XLSX.jl version you are using. The XLSX documentation actually has a while section devoted to this [here](https://felipenoris.github.io/XLSX.jl/stable/migration/). The relevant bit for you is that `readtable` now returns a Tables.jl compatible table and so can passed into the DataFrame constructor directly, so instead of

```
DataFrame(XLSX.readtable(myfile, sheet)...)
```

You do

```
DataFrame(XLSX.readtable(myfile, sheet))
```

(note the lack of the splatting operator)

Note that these kinds of issues are expected when you move between breaking releases of a package according to Semver, so either between major releases (version 1.x to version 2.x) or between minor releases pre 1.0 (eg 0.5.x to 0.6.x). If you want to avoid these issues you should work with project specific environments so that the Manifest records the versions of all packages you are using and they don't change unless you manually do `] up` for that specific environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful hint. It was indeed due to the different version of XLSX .  Migration to the newer version of Julia was done on another computer. There was also installed a newer version of XLSX unnoticed by me. Removal of the splatting operator eliminated all problems. Thank you very much !

Comment: Glad it worked. Manifests of course are portable across computers, so if you had used a project-specific Manifest you could have put that onto the new machine and then `]instantiate`d it. In that way you ensure that all dependencies stay on the same version used previously (unless this isn't possible because something doesn't support the new Julia version of course). Then you won't have "unnoticed" new versions, as you need to call `]up` explicitly to get newer versions of packages.

Comment: Also could you accept my answer as a solution, so that others following the Julia tag on here know this question is resolved?